# NGRX 4 effects with angular 4.3 httpClient

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular4-httpclient

Hi Stackoverflow team!

I have this effect, and i'm using ngrx 4 with angular 4.3 httpClient on the service.
The problem is that I could not see any examples on how to used them together. 
I saw that now, with httpclient we need to use the subscribe() method, so it is not clear to be, what to return, for example on the following code :

```
@Effect()
login$ = this.actions$
.ofType(Auth.LOGIN)
.map((action: Auth.Login) => action.payload)
.exhaustMap(auth =>
  this.authService
    .login(auth)
    .map(user => new Auth.LoginSuccess({ user }))
    .catch(error => of(new Auth.LoginFailure(error)))
);
```

So, i need to understand the logic on this line:
    .login(auth)
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The `.exhaustMap` is an operator that will **subscribe** to any observables that are returned by the callback code. It's going to keep listening until the observable is complete. You might want to add a `.login(auth).take(1)` if you know there will always be just one response.

`@Effect` declares a property variable as an `Observable<action>`. During bootstrapping the ngrx library will be the one that calls `subscribe` on all effects registered in your application.

That's why you don't see a `subscribe` call in any of the documentation. This is done for you by the library.